# I am scraping the korea flight website through api is not getting the required data

Tags: python, api, web-scraping

I want to scrape the korea flight website which have given hidden api of contuniue flights
but when i check it in postman it works and show the results and when i try it in requests using python it show me blank records.
this is the website `https://suvarnabhumi.airportthai.co.th/flight` and this is the api
'https://apis.airportthai.co.th/' with request payload given in the following code:

```
import requests
from requests import session
import json
from pprint import pprint


headers = {
  #"Content-Type": "application/text;",
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36",
  "Accept" : "*/*",
  "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
  "Connection": "keep-alive",
  "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,ur;q=0.8",
  "sec-ch-ua": 'Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"',
  "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
  "Referer": "https://suvarnabhumi.airportthai.co.th/"
}

data = {"query":"\n      query ($site: String, $type: FlightType, $search: String, $schedule_start: String, $schedule_end: String) {\n        flights(site: $site, type: $type, search: $search, schedule_start: $schedule_start, schedule_end: $schedule_end) {\n          flight_id\n          number\n          airline_id\n          aircraft_id\n          departure_scheduled_at\n          arrival_scheduled_at\n          flight_departure {\n            id\n            site_id\n            remark\n            terminal\n            gate\n            check_in_counter\n            status_color\n            estimated_at\n            actual_at\n            scheduled_at\n            updated_at\n            flight_shares\n            __typename\n          }\n          flight_arrival {\n            id\n            site_id\n            belt\n            terminal\n            remark\n            status_color\n            estimated_at\n            first_bag_at\n            last_bag_at\n            flight_shares\n            __typename\n          }\n          origin_airport {\n            id\n            name\n            city\n            iata_code\n            icao_code\n            __typename\n          }\n          destination_airport {\n            id\n            name\n            city\n            iata_code\n            icao_code\n            __typename\n          }\n          airline {\n            id\n            iata\n            icao\n            name\n            logo\n            __typename\n          }\n          aircraft {\n            id\n            name\n            iata\n            icao\n            __typename\n          }\n          updated_at\n          __typename\n        }\n      }\n      ","variables":{"site":"bkk","type":"A","search":"","schedule_start":"2021-08-24 11:49:00","schedule_end":"2021-08-24 23:59:59"}}

url = " https://apis.airportthai.co.th/"

r = requests.post(url,  data = data, headers = headers)

print(r.json())
```

when it run it give me blank results:

```
{'data': {'flights': []}}
```

In postman it shows all the data but here it does not work
here is the api in website
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working solution from my side:

Code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json


body = {"query": "\n      query ($site: String, $type: FlightType, $search: String, $schedule_start: String, $schedule_end: String) {\n        flights(site: $site, type: $type, search: $search, schedule_start: $schedule_start, schedule_end: $schedule_end) {\n          flight_id\n          number\n          airline_id\n          aircraft_id\n          departure_scheduled_at\n          arrival_scheduled_at\n          flight_departure {\n            id\n            site_id\n            remark\n            terminal\n            gate\n            check_in_counter\n            status_color\n            estimated_at\n            actual_at\n            scheduled_at\n            updated_at\n            flight_shares\n            __typename\n          }\n          flight_arrival {\n            id\n            site_id\n            belt\n            terminal\n            remark\n            status_color\n            estimated_at\n            first_bag_at\n            last_bag_at\n            flight_shares\n            __typename\n          }\n          origin_airport {\n            id\n            name\n            city\n            iata_code\n            icao_code\n            __typename\n          }\n          destination_airport {\n            id\n            name\n            city\n            iata_code\n            icao_code\n            __typename\n          }\n          airline {\n            id\n            iata\n            icao\n            name\n            logo\n            __typename\n          }\n          aircraft {\n            id\n            name\n            iata\n            icao\n            __typename\n          }\n          updated_at\n          __typename\n        }\n      }\n      ", "variables": {"site": "bkk", "type": "A", "search": "", "schedule_start": "2021-09-10 21:38:00", "schedule_end": "2021-09-10 23:59:59"}}
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8,es;q=0.7,ar;q=0.6",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "1843",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Host": "apis.airportthai.co.th",
    "Origin": "https://suvarnabhumi.airportthai.co.th",
    "Referer": "https://suvarnabhumi.airportthai.co.th/",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0"
    }


url = "https://apis.airportthai.co.th/"

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
response = r.json()['data']['flights']
for resp in response:
    print(resp['number'])
```

OUTPUT: Example
FLIGHT NUMBER

```
SG 089
VZ 317
TG 466
WE 137
ZE 761
LJ 011
TG 677
TR 850
KL 820
TG 222
TG 625
ZG 051
TG 418
TG 410
WE 121
KL 804
FD 4127
TG 482
TG 585
VZ 345
TG 607
KE 651
TG 436
WE 591
VZ 2107
WE 288
TG 635
WE 268
JL 707
TG 679
OZ 741
VZ 311
FD 4303
NH 805
RJ 181
VZ 329
VZ 3971
FD 4109
LJ 001
EK 385
7C 2215
CX 617
KE 659
VZ 121
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
data = {"query":"query($site: String, $type: FlightType, $search: String, $schedule_start: String, $schedule_end: String) {flights(site: $site, type: $type, search: $search, schedule_start: $schedule_start, schedule_end: $schedule_end) {flight_id number airline_id aircraft_id departure_scheduled_at arrival_scheduled_at flight_departure {id site_id remark terminal gate check_in_counter status_color estimated_at actual_at scheduled_at updated_at flight_shares __typename}flight_arrival {id site_id belt terminal remark status_color estimated_at first_bag_at last_bag_at flight_shares __typename}origin_airport {id name city iata_code icao_code  __typename}destination_airport {id name city iata_code icao_code __typename}airline {id iata icao name logo  __typename}aircraft {id name iata icao __typename}updated_at __typename}}","variables":{"site":"bkk","type":"A","search":"","schedule_start":"2021-09-10 00:00:00","schedule_end":"2021-09-10 23:59:59"}}

url = " https://apis.airportthai.co.th/"

from urllib import request
import json

req = request.Request(url, method='POST')
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
r = request.urlopen(req, data=json.dumps(data).encode())
print(r.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
import requests

    url = "https://apis.airportthai.co.th/"
    data = {"query":"\n      query ($site: String, $type: FlightType, $search: String,"
                    " $schedule_start: String, $schedule_end: String) {\n        "
                    "flights(site: $site, type: $type, search: $search, schedule_start: "
                    "$schedule_start, schedule_end: $schedule_end) {\n          flight_id\n         "
                    " number\n          airline_id\n          aircraft_id\n        "
                    "  departure_scheduled_at\n          arrival_scheduled_at\n         "
                    " flight_departure {\n            id\n            site_id\n           "
                    " remark\n            terminal\n            gate\n            check_in_counter\n   "
                    "         status_color\n            estimated_at\n            actual_at\n           "
                    " scheduled_at\n            updated_at\n            flight_shares\n           "
                    " __typename\n          }\n          flight_arrival {\n            id\n           "
                    " site_id\n            belt\n            terminal\n            remark\n            "
                    "status_color\n            estimated_at\n            first_bag_at\n            "
                    "last_bag_at\n            flight_shares\n            __typename\n          }\n         "
                    " origin_airport {\n            id\n            name\n            city\n            "
                    "iata_code\n            icao_code\n            __typename\n          }\n        "
                    "  destination_airport {\n            id\n            name\n            city\n            "
                    "iata_code\n            icao_code\n            __typename\n          }\n          airline {\n"
                    "            id\n            iata\n            icao\n            name\n            logo\n         "
                    "   __typename\n          }\n          aircraft {\n            id\n            name\n           "
                    " iata\n            icao\n            __typename\n          }\n          updated_at\n          "
                    "__typename\n        }\n      }\n      ",
            "variables":{"site":"bkk","type":"A","search":"","schedule_start":"2021-09-10 17:10:00","schedule_end":"2021-09-10 23:59:59"}}
    response = requests.post(url, json=data)
    print(response.json())
```

Probably the length of the data line is to big.

The headers you're providing are not necessary.

Also while submitting the payload use `json` format not row form data